# The elements of a drawing on a single page is exported as a multi-page PDF in Inkscape Version 1.3

Tags: graphics, inkscape, drawing2d

I drew a few elements (actually, lines) in inkscape and added some 'text' elements in-between. When the did 'Save a copy' as PDF (with text in separate file by choosing 'Omit Text in PDF and create LaTeX file' option from File > Save a Copy... dialog box), I found that Inkscape created a PDF with more than one page despite the original drawing was on a single page. How can I get all the elements (other than text) in a single page PDF?

I tried to redraw the elements after deleting the offending elements.

Comment: I have found a not-so-good solution. The solution I have found is to open the original drawing (SVG file) in a text editor and grouping the <path> elements together. This results in a single page PDF.